# Problemas para guardar usando CreateView, Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo este formulario, el porque del ***init*** es porque la tabla no permite el ingreso de NULL o vacíos, el porque no modifico la tabla, es porque tengo muchas y modificar cada campo, resultaría mal, igual en algún momento se puede dejar sin registrar algo, en fin

Este es mi formulario para obtener el ID del Usuario logeado

La vista

```py
class MenuCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Menu
    form_class = MenuForm
    template_name = 'create_menu.html'
    success_url = '/seguridad/menu'

    def get_initial(self):
        # Get the initial dictionary from the superclass method
        initial = super(MenuCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial = initial.copy()
        user_id = self.request.user.pk
        print('user_id inicial\t', user_id)
        # men_FechaCreacion
        initial['men_usuariocreacion'] = user_id
        initial['men_fechacreacion'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

y este es el error que me retorno

```py
No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'men_FechaCreacion'
```

mi pregunta es porque no toma en cuenta los "valores iniciales" al momento de guardar

no tengo implementado un `def form_valid` o `def save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no le encontré uso al *get_init*

todo quedo en

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
        """Force the user to request.user"""
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.men_codigo = int(Menu.objects.values(
            'men_codigo').latest('men_codigo')['men_codigo'])+1
        self.object.men_fechacreacion = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.object.men_usuariocreacion = self.request.user.id
```

para asignar valores iniciales a *campos NO NULL*

ahora el problema es porque no guarda el estado, siendo este un boleano

```py
widgets = {
            'men_estatus': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control py-2', 'type': 'checkbox', 'id': 'men_estatus', 'name': 'men_estatus'}),
        }
```

pero no carga el valor, y solo me guarda NULL, evidentemente tampoco me permite editar. Para campos boleanos ah sido *CheckboxInput* no textinput

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar como una nueva variable en el init el ID del usuario, algo como:

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, user_id *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['men_usuariocreacion'] = user_id
```

Si estas usando Clases genericas de django, en el get_form_kwargs puedes agregar esa varriable.

Comment: al implementar esto me sale este error `AttributeError at /seguridad/create-menu
'str' object has no attribute 'get_bound_field`; en el *get_form_kwargs* agregue `kwargs['user_id'] = self.request.user.pk`

Comment: segun la consola si trae el ID `{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'instance': None, 'user_id': 1}` porque se da el error, y si lo recibe tambien lo imprimi... entonces porque el error. El HTML lo presento solo con `{{form.as_p}}` y justo ahí me marca el error

Comment: Muestra el código modificado tanto del form como de la clase del get_form_kwargs

Comment: listo, de antemano gracias. Por lo menos es un error diferente jaajja